bash jumplist like in vim
I want to remap bash ctrl + i / ctrl + o to jump between workdirs, meaning directories where after diving into them (with cd) I invoked other commands than a mere cd or ls. I think the easiest is probably to take up the folder into a list, maybe using pushd and popd, but I don't want to invoke these commands manually, it should be taken care of by some hook maybe? Is this or something similar possible in bash? If so, how?
(Let's ignore for a moment that ctrl+i will also remap my tabkey, I'll take care of this)

You could switch to zsh which as cd +3 / cd -4 and more generally ~3, ~-4 (with completion if you enable it with compinit)  to navigate the $dirstack (populated with cd/pushd/popd/autocd).

What's a folder operation? What does uttering a folder mean?

@StéphaneChazelas uttering = me invoking an operation, note I did specify to "utter a cd or ls". I'm not switching to zsh since this is a bash question.

Like echo Please find it in /etc would be uttering an operation that mentions at least one directory (/etc, though find, it, in, Please may also be directories)?

@StéphaneChazelas I meant to only consider directories that i actively dived into using cd.

Oh, so does folders that I previously invoked more than just a cd or ls actually mean directories I've cd'ed into and from within which I've run any command other than ls? I take it you don't use pushd/popd?

Please [edit] your question and clarify. To utter means to speak out loud, it doesn't make sense in this context. And in the question you say that you want this to work for anything except cd or ls but in the comments you now say you want it instead only for directories you have cded into. So please [edit] the question and describe the behavior you need in more detail. Are you just looking for the pushd/popd bash builtins (see man bash and help popd or help pushd)?

@terdon Yeh uttered was the wrong word, fixed the description.

@StéphaneChazelas Exactly. I don't manually want to use pushd / popd, I think I want this to be taken care of by the facility in question :)

One could create a function named cd and add/do whatever you want to do with the directories, but builtin cd will be ignored and probably if autocd is enabled, Unless of course the builtin utility is a function of your own making. That said PROMPT_COMMAND and the builtin bind utility is probably a start.

@Jetchisel I also thought about PROMT_COMMAND. But is there a way to retrieve the previous readline so that I can dispatch based on the command used?
